# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column countries

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Error like that...How can i solve that?

Country database
[image]

[image]

This is country model

This is Challenge database
[image]

[image]

This is Challenge model

[image]

```
@foreach ($challenges as $challenge)
  <tr>                                 
     <td>{{$challenge->c_sport_id}}</td>
     <td>{{$challenge->c_gender}}</td>
     <td>{{$challenge->c_location}}
     <td>{{$challenge->countries->country_name}}</td>
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Can you show your controller and your tables (countries, challenges)?

Comment: did `countries` have `challenge_id` in your table?

Comment: If possible, it is easier to see if you can write from the code in the screenshot

Comment: Please do not post code or error messages as images. It’s text so include it as is and format it correctly so everyone can read it.

Comment: No challenges have country_id in your table? -@TsaiKoga

Comment: I added table of country and challenge -@RyanNghiem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your relation

```
<?php

class Challenge extends Model
{

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Country::class, 'c_country_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Comment: Trying to get property 'country_name' of non-object  -@Vikas Katariya

Comment: {{$challange[$countries]['country_name]}}

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your **Challenge Model**. You have country id in your challenge model. So you should use relationship **belongsTo** instead of **hasOne**. So change your **Challenge Model** relationship like this:-

```
<?php

class Challenge extends Model
{

    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Country::class, 'c_country_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

This is the correct one.

Comment: I think this was the problem